# Adding docker run flags to ECS operator in airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, amazon-ecs, flags

I'm using ECSOperator in airflow and I need to pass flags to the docker run. I searched the internet but I couldn't find a way to give an ECSOperator flags such as: -D, --cpus and more.

Is there a way to pass these flags to a docker run (if a certain condition is true) using the ECSOperator (same way we can pass tags, and network configuration), or they can only be defined in the ECS container running the docker image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `ECSOpearor` but if I understand correctly that is python library. And you can [create new task using python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-ecs-operator.html)

As I can see in this exmaple it is possible to set `task_definition` and `overrides`:

```py
...
ecs_operator_task = ECSOperator(
    task_id = "ecs_operator_task",
    dag=dag,
    cluster=CLUSTER_NAME,
    task_definition=service['services'][0]['taskDefinition'],
    launch_type=LAUNCH_TYPE,
    overrides={
        "containerOverrides":[
            {
                "name":CONTAINER_NAME,
                "command":["ls", "-l", "/"],
            },
        ],
    },
    network_configuration=service['services'][0]['networkConfiguration'],
    awslogs_group="mwaa-ecs-zero",
    awslogs_stream_prefix=f"ecs/{CONTAINER_NAME}",
...
```

So if you want to set CPU and Memory specs for whole task you have to update [`task_definition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html) dictionary parameters (something like `service['services'][0]['taskDefinition']['cpu'] = 2048`)
If you want to specify parameters for exact container, `overrides` should be proper way:

```py
overrides={
    "containerOverrides":[
        {
            "cpu": 2048,
            ...
        },
    ],
},
```

Or edited `containerDefinitions` may be set directly inside `task_definition` in theory...

Anyway most of docker parameters should be pass inside `containerDefinitions` section.

So about your question:

> Is there a way to pass these flags to a docker run

If I understand correctly you have a JSON `TaskDefinition` file and want to run it locally using docker?
Then try to [check these tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296483/ecs-equivalent-of-docker-composes-command). It allows you to convert `docker-compose.yml` into ECS definition, and that is opposite of what you looking for, but maybe some of these tools able to convert it vice-versa..?
In other way you have to parse `TaskDefinition`'s JSON manually and convert it to docker command arguments